# I am working in svg file with animation is not working in forefox and i am using svg in image tag

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, fill

Here is my code for svg and html there are some of div that are containing with st0 class. When i am trying to run in firefox its not fading in with these st0 class name but working fine in other browser. please help me

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en" class="no-js">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="image/svg+xml" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 

<title>SVG</title>
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body style="text-align:center; background-color:black">

<img src="jeebs-media.svg".svg" style="margin-top:30px;">

</body> 
</html>





 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
 <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"> 
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200px" height="200px"
 viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve">
 <style type="text/css">
.st0{fill:#ffffff !important; }
.st1{fill:#C12461;}
.st2{fill:#E92233;}
.st3{fill:#F16726;}
.st4{fill:#FFC216;}
.st5{fill:#C9D92E;}
.st6{fill:#26B8EB;}
.st7{fill:#218ECD;}
.st8{fill:#0D519E;}
.st9{fill:#66328F;}
.st10{fill:#962B79;}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0.0; } to { opacity:1.0; } }
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0.0; } to { opacity:1.0; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0.0; } to { opacity:1.0; } }
@-ms-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0.0; } to { opacity:1.0; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0.0; } to { opacity:1.0; } }



 .fade-in {

 opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
-webkit-animation: fadeIn 1.0s ease-in;
   -moz-animation: fadeIn 1.0s ease-in;
    -ms-animation: fadeIn 1.0s ease-in;
     -o-animation: fadeIn 1.0s ease-in;
        animation: fadeIn 1.0s ease-in;

-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
   -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
     -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
        animation-fill-mode: forwards; 

-webkit-animation-duration: 2.0s; 
   -moz-animation-duration: 2.0s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 2.0s; 
     -o-animation-duration: 2.0s;
        animation-duration: 2.0s;

-webkit-animation-delay: 2.0s; 
   -moz-animation-delay: 2.0s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.0s; 
     -o-animation-delay: 2.0s;
        animation-delay: 2.0s;
  }

  </style>
  <g class="text fade-in">
  <g>
    <g>
        <path class="st0"  d="M38.9,155.3c0,1.5-0.3,2.7-1,3.5c-0.6,0.8-1.6,1.2-2.9,1.2c-0.5,0-1-0.1-1.4-0.2c-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.4-1.2-0.7
            c-0.4-0.3-0.7-0.7-0.9-1.2c-0.3-0.5-0.4-1.1-0.6-1.8l-2.2,0.4c0.4,1.9,1.1,3.3,2.1,4.1c1,0.9,2.4,1.3,4.1,1.3
            c1,0,1.9-0.2,2.7-0.5c0.8-0.3,1.4-0.8,1.9-1.4c0.5-0.6,0.9-1.3,1.2-2.1c0.3-0.8,0.4-1.7,0.4-2.8v-15.7h-2.2V155.3z"/>
        <polygon class="st0" points="61.2,151.2 70.4,151.2 70.4,149.3 61.2,149.3 61.2,141.4 73.5,141.4 73.5,139.5 58.9,139.5 
            58.9,161.6 74.2,161.6 74.2,159.7 61.2,159.7             "/>
        <polygon class="st0" points="92.8,151.2 102.3,151.2 102.3,149.3 92.8,149.3 92.8,141.4 105.1,141.4 105.1,139.5 90.6,139.5 
            90.6,161.6 105.8,161.6 105.8,159.7 92.8,159.7           "/>
        <path class="st0" d="M137.3,151.8c-0.5-0.5-1-0.9-1.7-1.2c-0.7-0.3-1.5-0.5-2.4-0.6c0.7-0.2,1.3-0.4,1.8-0.7
            c0.5-0.3,1-0.7,1.3-1.1c0.3-0.4,0.6-0.9,0.8-1.5c0.2-0.6,0.3-1.1,0.3-1.8c0-0.9-0.2-1.7-0.5-2.4c-0.3-0.7-0.9-1.2-1.5-1.7
            c-0.7-0.4-1.5-0.7-2.4-0.9c-0.9-0.2-2-0.3-3.2-0.3h-7.7v22.1h8.6c1.1,0,2.1-0.1,3-0.3c1-0.2,1.8-0.6,2.5-1.1
            c0.7-0.5,1.3-1.1,1.7-1.9c0.4-0.8,0.6-1.7,0.6-2.9c0-0.7-0.1-1.4-0.4-2C138.1,152.8,137.8,152.2,137.3,151.8z M124.4,141.3h5.3
            c1.8,0,3.2,0.3,4.1,0.9c0.9,0.6,1.3,1.5,1.3,2.8c0,0.6-0.1,1.2-0.3,1.7c-0.2,0.5-0.5,0.9-1,1.3c-0.4,0.4-1,0.6-1.7,0.8
            c-0.7,0.2-1.5,0.3-2.4,0.3h-5.4V141.3z M136,157.4c-0.3,0.6-0.7,1.1-1.3,1.4c-0.5,0.4-1.2,0.6-1.9,0.8c-0.7,0.2-1.5,0.2-2.3,0.2
            h-6v-8.9h5.8c0.9,0,1.8,0.1,2.5,0.3c0.8,0.2,1.4,0.4,1.9,0.8c0.5,0.4,1,0.8,1.3,1.4c0.3,0.5,0.5,1.2,0.5,1.9
            C136.4,156.1,136.3,156.8,136,157.4z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M170.9,153.6c-0.2-0.6-0.5-1.1-0.9-1.5c-0.4-0.4-0.8-0.8-1.3-1.1c-0.5-0.3-1-0.5-1.6-0.8
            c-0.6-0.2-1.2-0.4-1.8-0.6c-0.6-0.2-1.2-0.3-1.9-0.5c-0.8-0.2-1.6-0.4-2.3-0.6c-0.7-0.2-1.4-0.5-1.9-0.8c-0.5-0.3-1-0.7-1.3-1.2
            c-0.3-0.5-0.5-1.1-0.5-1.8c0-0.5,0.1-1.1,0.3-1.5c0.2-0.5,0.5-0.9,0.9-1.2c0.4-0.4,1-0.6,1.7-0.8c0.7-0.2,1.5-0.3,2.5-0.3
            c0.9,0,1.7,0.1,2.3,0.3c0.6,0.2,1.2,0.4,1.6,0.7c0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7,1.1,1.1c0.3,0.4,0.5,1,0.6,1.5l2.2-0.5
            c-0.2-0.8-0.5-1.5-0.9-2.1c-0.4-0.6-0.9-1.1-1.5-1.5c-0.6-0.4-1.4-0.7-2.3-0.9c-0.9-0.2-1.9-0.3-3.2-0.3c-1.1,0-2.1,0.1-3,0.3
            c-0.9,0.2-1.7,0.6-2.4,1c-0.7,0.5-1.2,1.1-1.6,1.8c-0.4,0.7-0.6,1.6-0.6,2.6c0,0.7,0.1,1.3,0.3,1.9c0.2,0.5,0.5,1,0.8,1.4
            c0.3,0.4,0.7,0.7,1.2,1c0.5,0.3,0.9,0.5,1.5,0.7c0.5,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.6,0.6c0.6,0.2,1.1,0.3,1.7,0.4c0.8,0.2,1.6,0.4,2.4,0.6
            c0.8,0.2,1.5,0.5,2.1,0.8c0.6,0.3,1.1,0.8,1.5,1.3c0.4,0.5,0.6,1.2,0.6,2c0,0.8-0.2,1.4-0.5,2c-0.3,0.6-0.7,1-1.3,1.4
            c-0.5,0.3-1.2,0.6-1.9,0.8c-0.7,0.2-1.6,0.3-2.4,0.3c-1,0-1.9-0.1-2.7-0.3c-0.8-0.2-1.4-0.5-1.9-0.9c-0.5-0.4-0.9-0.8-1.2-1.3
            c-0.3-0.5-0.5-1-0.7-1.6l-2.2,0.5c0.4,1.7,1.3,3.1,2.7,4c1.4,0.9,3.4,1.4,5.9,1.4c1.4,0,2.6-0.2,3.7-0.5c1-0.3,1.9-0.8,2.6-1.3
            c0.7-0.6,1.2-1.2,1.5-2c0.3-0.8,0.5-1.6,0.5-2.5C171.2,154.8,171.1,154.2,170.9,153.6z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st0"  d="M56.8,181.6v-5.3c0-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.5c0-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5c0-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.4c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5
            c0,0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4l-2.3,5.4h-0.7l-2.4-5.4c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4
            c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5c0,0.2,0,0.3,0,0.5c0,0.1,0,0.3,0,0.5c0,0.2,0,0.3,0,0.5v5.3h-0.7v-7.6h1l2.5,5.7c0,0,0,0.1,0.1,0.2
            c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.2-0.5c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4c0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.2l2.4-5.7h1
            v7.6H56.8z"/>
        <path class="st0"  d="M76.3,181.6v-7.6h5v0.6h-4.3v2.7H81v0.6h-3.9v3h4.5v0.6H76.3z"/>
        <path class="st0"   d="M106.4,177.7c0,0.6-0.1,1.2-0.3,1.7c-0.2,0.5-0.5,0.9-0.8,1.2c-0.3,0.3-0.7,0.6-1.2,0.7
            c-0.4,0.2-0.9,0.2-1.5,0.2h-2.8v-7.6h2.4c0.6,0,1.1,0.1,1.6,0.2c0.5,0.1,0.9,0.4,1.3,0.7c0.4,0.3,0.6,0.7,0.8,1.2
            C106.3,176.5,106.4,177,106.4,177.7z M105.6,177.7c0-0.5-0.1-1-0.2-1.4c-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.7-0.7-1c-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.4-1-0.5
            c-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.2-1.3-0.2h-1.6v6.3h1.9c0.4,0,0.8-0.1,1.2-0.2c0.4-0.1,0.7-0.3,1-0.6c0.3-0.3,0.5-0.6,0.6-1
            C105.5,178.7,105.6,178.2,105.6,177.7z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M124.9,181.6v-7.6h0.8v7.6H124.9z"/>
        <path class="st0"  d="M149.5,181.6l-0.9-2.4h-3.4l-0.9,2.4h-0.8l3-7.6h0.9l3,7.6H149.5z M147.4,175.9c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5
            c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3c0-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.1c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.2c0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3
            c0,0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5l-1,2.7h3L147.4,175.9z"/>
    </g>
</g>

</g>
<g class="icon">
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st1" d="M102.3,18.5c-4.8-0.1-9.5,0.5-14,1.8c-4.5,1.3-8.8,3.3-12.7,6c-3.9,2.7-7.4,6.1-10.2,10.1
            c-2.9,4.1-5,8.9-6.2,14.2c-0.4,2.2-0.5,4.5-0.1,6.7c0.3,2.2,1.1,4.4,2.1,6.5c1,2.1,2.4,4,4,5.6c1.6,1.7,3.5,3.1,5.5,4.1
            c0.8,0.4,1.6,0.7,2.4,1c0.8,0.3,1.7,0.5,2.5,0.6c0.9,0.1,1.7,0.2,2.6,0.2c0.9,0,1.8,0,2.7-0.2c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.2
            c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.2c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.2c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.2c-2.8-1.4-5.1-3.2-7-5.4c-1.9-2.2-3.3-4.6-4.3-7.3
            c-1-2.6-1.5-5.4-1.7-8.3c-0.1-2.8,0.1-5.7,0.7-8.6c0.2-0.7,0.4-1.4,0.7-2.2c0.3-0.8,0.6-1.6,1.1-2.5c0.4-0.9,0.9-1.8,1.4-2.7
            c0.5-0.9,1.1-1.8,1.8-2.8c1.7-2.5,3.7-4.7,6-6.6c2.3-1.9,4.9-3.5,7.6-4.8c2.7-1.3,5.5-2.4,8.4-3.2
            C96.6,19.3,99.5,18.7,102.3,18.5"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st2" d="M124.8,23.5c-4.3-2.1-9.1-3.5-13.8-4.2c-4.8-0.7-9.7-0.7-14.4,0c-4.7,0.8-9.2,2.3-13.1,4.7
            c-4,2.4-7.4,5.8-9.8,10.1c-1.4,1.9-2.4,4-2.9,6.3c-0.6,2.3-0.7,4.8-0.3,7.1c0.4,2.4,1.3,4.7,2.7,6.7c1.4,2,3.3,3.8,5.8,5
            c-1.3-2.7-2.1-5.7-2.5-8.7c-0.3-3-0.2-6,0.5-8.9c0.6-2.8,1.7-5.5,3.3-7.9c1.5-2.3,3.5-4.3,5.9-5.8c0.5-0.4,1.2-0.8,1.8-1.3
            c0.7-0.4,1.4-0.9,2.3-1.3c0.8-0.4,1.7-0.9,2.7-1.3c0.9-0.4,2-0.8,3-1.2c2.6-0.8,5.3-1.4,7.9-1.7c2.7-0.3,5.4-0.3,8.1-0.1
            c2.7,0.2,5.4,0.7,8.1,1.5c2.7,0.8,5.4,1.8,8,3c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.9,0.4c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.9,0.5c0.3,0.2,0.6,0.3,0.9,0.5
            s0.6,0.3,0.9,0.5c-0.5-0.4-1.1-0.8-1.6-1.1c-0.6-0.4-1.1-0.7-1.7-1.1c-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.7-1.7-1C126,24.1,125.4,23.8,124.8,23.5"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st3" d="M122.2,23.5c-0.8-0.4-1.7-0.8-2.6-1.1c-0.9-0.4-1.8-0.7-2.7-1c-0.9-0.3-1.8-0.6-2.7-0.8
            c-0.9-0.2-1.9-0.5-2.8-0.6c-3.5-0.5-7.3-0.3-10.9,0.5c-3.7,0.9-7.2,2.4-10.1,4.5c-3,2.2-5.4,4.9-6.8,8.2
            c-1.4,3.3-1.7,7.2-0.4,11.4c0.7-3,1.9-5.7,3.6-8.2c1.6-2.4,3.7-4.5,6-6.3c2.3-1.7,4.8-3.1,7.5-4c2.7-0.9,5.4-1.5,8.3-1.5
            c0.7,0,1.4,0,2.3,0c0.8,0,1.7,0.1,2.6,0.2c0.9,0.1,1.9,0.3,2.9,0.5c1,0.2,2.1,0.5,3.2,0.8c0.6,0.1,1.1,0.3,1.7,0.4
            c0.6,0.2,1.1,0.3,1.6,0.5c0.5,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.6,0.6c0.5,0.2,1,0.4,1.5,0.7c2.2,1.1,4.2,2.4,6.1,3.9c1.9,1.5,3.7,3.2,5.5,5.1
            c1.8,1.9,3.5,3.8,5.1,5.9c1.7,2,3.4,4.1,5.1,6.2c-1.5-2.8-3.1-5.5-5-8.1c-1.8-2.5-3.8-4.9-6-7.1c-2.2-2.2-4.5-4.2-6.9-6
            C127.5,26.4,124.9,24.8,122.2,23.5"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st4" d="M123.8,28.9c-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.8-0.4c-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.8-0.4c-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.8-0.3
            c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.8-0.3c-2.5-0.6-5-0.9-7.5-0.7c-2.5,0.2-5,0.7-7.3,1.6c-2.3,0.9-4.5,2.3-6.3,4c-1.9,1.7-3.5,3.9-4.6,6.4
            c2.2-1.7,4.5-3.1,7-4.2c2.4-1,4.9-1.7,7.4-2c2.5-0.3,5-0.3,7.6,0.2c2.5,0.4,5.1,1.2,7.6,2.4c0.3,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.4
            c0.3,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.4c0.3,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.4c0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.5c0.6,0.4,1.2,0.8,1.9,1.3c0.7,0.5,1.3,1.1,2,1.7
            c0.7,0.6,1.4,1.3,2.2,2.1c0.7,0.8,1.5,1.6,2.2,2.5c2.1,2.4,3.7,5,4.9,7.9c1.3,2.9,2.2,6,2.9,9.2c0.7,3.2,1.1,6.6,1.3,10
            c0.2,3.4,0.3,6.9,0.2,10.2c1-5.3,1.3-10.8,0.9-16.1c-0.3-5.2-1.4-10.4-3.1-15.1c-1.7-4.7-4.1-9-7.3-12.7
            C132.5,34.3,128.6,31.2,123.8,28.9"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st5" d="M130,43.3c-1.5-0.7-3.1-1.3-4.6-1.6c-1.6-0.4-3.2-0.5-4.8-0.5c-1.6,0.1-3.2,0.4-4.7,0.9
            c-1.5,0.6-3.1,1.4-4.5,2.6c1.2-0.3,2.5-0.6,3.7-0.7c1.2-0.1,2.4-0.1,3.5,0c1.1,0.1,2.3,0.3,3.4,0.7c1.1,0.3,2.2,0.7,3.2,1.2
            c1.4,0.7,2.8,1.5,4.1,2.5c1.3,1,2.5,2.1,3.7,3.3c1.1,1.2,2.2,2.6,3.2,4c1,1.4,1.8,2.9,2.6,4.5c0.3,0.6,0.5,1.3,0.8,2.1
            c0.2,0.8,0.5,1.6,0.7,2.5c0.2,0.9,0.4,1.9,0.6,2.9c0.2,1,0.3,2.1,0.4,3.3c0.4,3.1,0.3,6.3-0.3,9.5c-0.6,3.2-1.6,6.3-3,9.4
            c-1.4,3.1-3.1,6.1-5.1,8.9c-2,2.8-4.3,5.5-6.7,7.8c3.8-3.1,7.1-6.7,9.8-10.6c2.7-3.8,4.8-8,6.3-12.3c1.5-4.2,2.3-8.6,2.5-13
            c0.2-4.3-0.2-8.7-1.4-12.9c-0.5-1.5-1.2-3-2.1-4.4c-0.9-1.4-1.9-2.8-3.1-4c-1.2-1.2-2.4-2.4-3.8-3.4
            C132.9,44.9,131.5,44,130,43.3"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st6" d="M130.8,53.6c-0.7-0.4-1.5-0.7-2.3-0.9c-0.8-0.3-1.6-0.5-2.4-0.7c-0.8-0.2-1.7-0.3-2.5-0.4
            c-0.9-0.1-1.7-0.1-2.6-0.1c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.2c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.2c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2
            c2.7,1.3,5,3,6.9,4.9c1.9,2,3.3,4.2,4.4,6.6c1,2.4,1.6,5,1.8,7.6c0.2,2.7-0.1,5.4-0.9,8c-0.2,0.7-0.4,1.4-0.6,2.2
            c-0.3,0.8-0.6,1.6-1,2.5c-0.4,0.9-0.8,1.8-1.3,2.7c-0.5,0.9-1.1,1.9-1.7,2.9c-2.1,2.5-4.4,5-6.9,7.2c-2.6,2.3-5.4,4.3-8.4,6.1
            c-3,1.8-6.3,3.2-9.8,4.1c-3.5,1-7.1,1.5-10.9,1.4c3.4,0.3,6.6,0.1,9.6-0.3c3-0.4,5.9-1.1,8.7-2.1c2.8-1,5.4-2.2,8-3.6
            c2.6-1.4,5.1-3,7.5-4.7c2.7-2.2,5.1-4.8,7.1-7.4c2-2.7,3.5-5.5,4.6-8.4c1.1-2.9,1.7-5.9,1.8-8.9c0.1-3-0.3-6-1.4-9
            c-0.4-1.2-0.9-2.3-1.5-3.3c-0.6-1-1.3-2-2.1-2.9c-0.8-0.9-1.7-1.7-2.7-2.4C132.9,54.8,131.9,54.2,130.8,53.6"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st7" d="M120.9,65.1c2,2.3,3.2,4.9,3.9,7.5c0.7,2.7,0.7,5.5,0.2,8.2c-0.5,2.8-1.5,5.6-2.9,8.2
            c-1.5,2.6-3.4,5.1-5.6,7.2c-0.5,0.5-1.2,1-1.9,1.5c-0.7,0.5-1.5,1-2.4,1.6c-0.9,0.5-1.8,1-2.8,1.5c-1,0.5-2.1,1-3.3,1.5
            c-3,1-6,1.7-9.2,2.1c-3.1,0.4-6.3,0.5-9.5,0.2c-3.2-0.2-6.3-0.8-9.3-1.6c-3-0.8-5.9-1.9-8.7-3.3c-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.3-0.9-0.5
            c-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.3-0.9-0.5c-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.3-0.9-0.5c-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.3-0.9-0.5c0.6,0.5,1.2,1,1.8,1.5c0.6,0.5,1.3,0.9,1.9,1.4
            c0.6,0.4,1.3,0.9,2,1.2c0.7,0.4,1.4,0.8,2.1,1.1c2.3,1.1,4.7,2,7.1,2.7c2.5,0.7,5,1.1,7.5,1.4c2.6,0.3,5.1,0.4,7.7,0.3
            c2.5-0.1,5.1-0.3,7.6-0.6c4-0.7,7.8-1.9,11.2-3.4c3.3-1.6,6.3-3.5,8.7-5.9c2.4-2.4,4.3-5.1,5.5-8.3c1.2-3.1,1.8-6.6,1.6-10.4
            c0-1.4-0.2-2.8-0.7-4.1c-0.4-1.3-1.1-2.6-1.9-3.8c-0.8-1.2-1.9-2.2-3.1-3.2C123.7,66.7,122.4,65.9,120.9,65.1"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st8" d="M116.9,76.9c0.1,3.2-0.3,6.2-1.4,8.9c-1,2.7-2.6,5.1-4.6,7.1c-2,2.1-4.4,3.8-7.1,5.1
            c-2.7,1.3-5.7,2.2-8.9,2.7c-0.7,0.1-1.6,0.1-2.5,0.2c-0.9,0-1.9,0-2.9,0c-1-0.1-2.1-0.2-3.3-0.3c-1.2-0.1-2.4-0.4-3.6-0.6
            c-0.7-0.1-1.3-0.3-2-0.5c-0.6-0.2-1.3-0.4-1.9-0.6c-0.6-0.2-1.3-0.5-1.9-0.7c-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.5-1.8-0.8c-2.4-1.2-4.6-2.6-6.7-4.2
            c-2.1-1.6-4.1-3.4-6.1-5.4c-1.9-1.9-3.7-3.9-5.4-6c-1.7-2-3.3-4.1-4.8-6.1c1.1,2.7,2.4,5.3,4,7.9c1.6,2.6,3.4,5,5.5,7.3
            c2.1,2.3,4.4,4.5,6.9,6.4c2.5,1.9,5.2,3.6,8,5c2.6,1.3,5.2,2.3,8,3c2.7,0.7,5.5,1.1,8.4,1.2c2.8,0.1,5.7-0.2,8.5-0.8
            c2.8-0.6,5.7-1.7,8.4-3.1c2.1-1.2,3.9-2.9,5.4-4.8c1.4-1.9,2.5-4.1,3.2-6.5c0.6-2.3,0.9-4.8,0.7-7.2
            C118.7,81.6,118.1,79.2,116.9,76.9"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st9" d="M56.4,48.5c-1.1,4.4-1.4,8.9-1.1,13.5c0.3,4.7,1.4,9.4,3.1,13.8c1.8,4.5,4.3,8.8,7.6,12.5
            c3.3,3.8,7.4,6.9,12.1,9.3c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.9,0.4c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.9,0.4c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,1,0.4c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,1,0.4
            c3.2,0.9,6.5,1.2,9.5,0.8c3-0.4,5.9-1.3,8.4-2.8c2.5-1.5,4.6-3.4,6.3-5.8c1.7-2.3,2.9-5.1,3.5-8.1c-1.3,2.5-3.1,4.5-5.3,6.2
            c-2.2,1.7-4.8,3-7.6,3.8c-2.8,0.8-5.7,1.2-8.7,1c-2.9-0.2-5.8-0.9-8.5-2.2c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.4
            c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.4c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.4c-0.7-0.3-1.4-0.7-2.2-1.2c-0.8-0.5-1.6-1-2.4-1.6c-0.8-0.6-1.7-1.3-2.6-2
            c-0.9-0.7-1.8-1.5-2.6-2.4c-2.4-2.6-4.3-5.4-5.8-8.2c-1.5-2.8-2.6-5.7-3.5-8.7c-0.8-3-1.3-6-1.5-9C56.2,54.6,56.2,51.6,56.4,48.5
            "/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st10" d="M71.1,25c-3.8,3.4-7.1,7.6-9.6,12.2c-2.6,4.7-4.4,9.9-5.2,15.2c-0.8,5.4-0.5,11,1.3,16.4
            c1.8,5.5,5,10.7,9.9,15.2c0.3,0.3,0.7,0.5,1,0.8c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.5,1,0.7c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.4,1.1,0.6c0.4,0.2,0.7,0.4,1.1,0.6
            c2.1,1,4.3,1.7,6.5,2c2.2,0.3,4.4,0.2,6.6-0.2c2.1-0.4,4.2-1.2,6-2.4c1.8-1.2,3.5-2.7,4.9-4.6c-1.7,0.7-3.4,1.3-5.2,1.6
            c-1.8,0.3-3.6,0.5-5.4,0.4c-1.8-0.1-3.7-0.3-5.4-0.8c-1.8-0.4-3.5-1.1-5.1-1.9c-1.2-0.6-2.3-1.3-3.4-2.1c-1.1-0.8-2.1-1.6-3-2.6
            c-0.9-1-1.8-2-2.5-3.1c-0.7-1.1-1.4-2.3-1.9-3.6c-0.4-0.6-0.7-1.4-1.1-2.2c-0.4-0.8-0.7-1.7-1.1-2.6c-0.3-0.9-0.7-1.9-0.9-3
            c-0.3-1.1-0.5-2.2-0.8-3.3c-0.1-3.2,0.1-6.3,0.5-9.5c0.4-3.1,1.1-6.1,2-9c0.9-2.8,2.1-5.6,3.6-8.1C67.2,29.4,69,27.1,71.1,25"/>
    </g>
</g>

<animateTransform attributeName="transform" 
     attributeType="XML" 
     type="rotate" 
     from="0 100 62" 
     to="360 100 62" 
     dur="4s" 
     repeatCount="0" 
     fill="freeze"           
/> 

</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is solved by using object tag and now its working fine.. I have changed only image tag to object tag..

```
 <object type="image/svg+xml" data="jeebs-media.svg"></object>
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a second `.svg"` in your image tag. Remove it and it should work as expected.

`<img src="jeebs-media.svg" style="margin-top:30px; color:#white!important; fill:currentColor;">`

Anyway you can only use your svg styles if you embed it in your svg image or use it directly as an `<svg></svg>` tag.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg

**EDIT:**

If you use an SVG tag you can apply your styles like so:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150" height="100" viewBox="0 0 3 2">
  .st0{fill:#ffffff;}
  .st1{fill:#C12461;}
  .st2{fill:#E92233;}
  .st3{fill:#F16726;}
  .st4{fill:#FFC216;}
  .st5{fill:#C9D92E;}
  .st6{fill:#26B8EB;}
  .st7{fill:#218ECD;}
  .st8{fill:#0D519E;}
  .st9{fill:#66328F;}
  .st10{fill:#962B79;}

  <rect class="st0" width="1" height="2" x="0"/>
  <rect class="st1" width="1" height="2" x="1"/>
  /..
</svg>
```

Or you can use a css file like so:

```
svg {
  color:white !important;
}
```

**EDIT2**

You got a missing `.text {fill:white;}` so u cant see the font animate. Add it to your code and its done.

```css
st0{fill:#ffffff !important; }
 .st1{fill:#C12461;}
 .st2{fill:#E92233;}
 .st3{fill:#F16726;}
 .st4{fill:#FFC216;}
 .st5{fill:#C9D92E;}
 .st6{fill:#26B8EB;}
 .st7{fill:#218ECD;}
 .st8{fill:#0D519E;}
 .st9{fill:#66328F;}
 .st10{fill:#962B79;}
  
  .text {fill:white;}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0.0; } to { opacity:1.0; } }
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0.0; } to { opacity:1.0; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0.0; } to { opacity:1.0; } }
@-ms-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0.0; } to { opacity:1.0; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0.0; } to { opacity:1.0; } }



.fade-in {
 
 opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
 -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1.0s ease-in;
       -moz-animation: fadeIn 1.0s ease-in;
        -ms-animation: fadeIn 1.0s ease-in;
         -o-animation: fadeIn 1.0s ease-in;
            animation: fadeIn 1.0s ease-in;
 
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
       -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
        -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
         -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
            animation-fill-mode: forwards; 

 -webkit-animation-duration: 2.0s; 
       -moz-animation-duration: 2.0s;
        -ms-animation-duration: 2.0s; 
         -o-animation-duration: 2.0s;
            animation-duration: 2.0s;
   
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2.0s; 
       -moz-animation-delay: 2.0s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 2.0s; 
         -o-animation-delay: 2.0s;
            animation-delay: 2.0s;
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center; background-color:black">

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200px" height="200px"
  viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve">
<g class="text fade-in">
 <g>
  <g>
   <path class="st0"  d="M38.9,155.3c0,1.5-0.3,2.7-1,3.5c-0.6,0.8-1.6,1.2-2.9,1.2c-0.5,0-1-0.1-1.4-0.2c-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.4-1.2-0.7
    c-0.4-0.3-0.7-0.7-0.9-1.2c-0.3-0.5-0.4-1.1-0.6-1.8l-2.2,0.4c0.4,1.9,1.1,3.3,2.1,4.1c1,0.9,2.4,1.3,4.1,1.3
    c1,0,1.9-0.2,2.7-0.5c0.8-0.3,1.4-0.8,1.9-1.4c0.5-0.6,0.9-1.3,1.2-2.1c0.3-0.8,0.4-1.7,0.4-2.8v-15.7h-2.2V155.3z"/>
   <polygon class="st0" points="61.2,151.2 70.4,151.2 70.4,149.3 61.2,149.3 61.2,141.4 73.5,141.4 73.5,139.5 58.9,139.5 
    58.9,161.6 74.2,161.6 74.2,159.7 61.2,159.7    "/>
   <polygon class="st0" points="92.8,151.2 102.3,151.2 102.3,149.3 92.8,149.3 92.8,141.4 105.1,141.4 105.1,139.5 90.6,139.5 
    90.6,161.6 105.8,161.6 105.8,159.7 92.8,159.7    "/>
   <path class="st0" d="M137.3,151.8c-0.5-0.5-1-0.9-1.7-1.2c-0.7-0.3-1.5-0.5-2.4-0.6c0.7-0.2,1.3-0.4,1.8-0.7
    c0.5-0.3,1-0.7,1.3-1.1c0.3-0.4,0.6-0.9,0.8-1.5c0.2-0.6,0.3-1.1,0.3-1.8c0-0.9-0.2-1.7-0.5-2.4c-0.3-0.7-0.9-1.2-1.5-1.7
    c-0.7-0.4-1.5-0.7-2.4-0.9c-0.9-0.2-2-0.3-3.2-0.3h-7.7v22.1h8.6c1.1,0,2.1-0.1,3-0.3c1-0.2,1.8-0.6,2.5-1.1
    c0.7-0.5,1.3-1.1,1.7-1.9c0.4-0.8,0.6-1.7,0.6-2.9c0-0.7-0.1-1.4-0.4-2C138.1,152.8,137.8,152.2,137.3,151.8z M124.4,141.3h5.3
    c1.8,0,3.2,0.3,4.1,0.9c0.9,0.6,1.3,1.5,1.3,2.8c0,0.6-0.1,1.2-0.3,1.7c-0.2,0.5-0.5,0.9-1,1.3c-0.4,0.4-1,0.6-1.7,0.8
    c-0.7,0.2-1.5,0.3-2.4,0.3h-5.4V141.3z M136,157.4c-0.3,0.6-0.7,1.1-1.3,1.4c-0.5,0.4-1.2,0.6-1.9,0.8c-0.7,0.2-1.5,0.2-2.3,0.2
    h-6v-8.9h5.8c0.9,0,1.8,0.1,2.5,0.3c0.8,0.2,1.4,0.4,1.9,0.8c0.5,0.4,1,0.8,1.3,1.4c0.3,0.5,0.5,1.2,0.5,1.9
    C136.4,156.1,136.3,156.8,136,157.4z"/>
   <path class="st0" d="M170.9,153.6c-0.2-0.6-0.5-1.1-0.9-1.5c-0.4-0.4-0.8-0.8-1.3-1.1c-0.5-0.3-1-0.5-1.6-0.8
    c-0.6-0.2-1.2-0.4-1.8-0.6c-0.6-0.2-1.2-0.3-1.9-0.5c-0.8-0.2-1.6-0.4-2.3-0.6c-0.7-0.2-1.4-0.5-1.9-0.8c-0.5-0.3-1-0.7-1.3-1.2
    c-0.3-0.5-0.5-1.1-0.5-1.8c0-0.5,0.1-1.1,0.3-1.5c0.2-0.5,0.5-0.9,0.9-1.2c0.4-0.4,1-0.6,1.7-0.8c0.7-0.2,1.5-0.3,2.5-0.3
    c0.9,0,1.7,0.1,2.3,0.3c0.6,0.2,1.2,0.4,1.6,0.7c0.5,0.3,0.8,0.7,1.1,1.1c0.3,0.4,0.5,1,0.6,1.5l2.2-0.5
    c-0.2-0.8-0.5-1.5-0.9-2.1c-0.4-0.6-0.9-1.1-1.5-1.5c-0.6-0.4-1.4-0.7-2.3-0.9c-0.9-0.2-1.9-0.3-3.2-0.3c-1.1,0-2.1,0.1-3,0.3
    c-0.9,0.2-1.7,0.6-2.4,1c-0.7,0.5-1.2,1.1-1.6,1.8c-0.4,0.7-0.6,1.6-0.6,2.6c0,0.7,0.1,1.3,0.3,1.9c0.2,0.5,0.5,1,0.8,1.4
    c0.3,0.4,0.7,0.7,1.2,1c0.5,0.3,0.9,0.5,1.5,0.7c0.5,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.6,0.6c0.6,0.2,1.1,0.3,1.7,0.4c0.8,0.2,1.6,0.4,2.4,0.6
    c0.8,0.2,1.5,0.5,2.1,0.8c0.6,0.3,1.1,0.8,1.5,1.3c0.4,0.5,0.6,1.2,0.6,2c0,0.8-0.2,1.4-0.5,2c-0.3,0.6-0.7,1-1.3,1.4
    c-0.5,0.3-1.2,0.6-1.9,0.8c-0.7,0.2-1.6,0.3-2.4,0.3c-1,0-1.9-0.1-2.7-0.3c-0.8-0.2-1.4-0.5-1.9-0.9c-0.5-0.4-0.9-0.8-1.2-1.3
    c-0.3-0.5-0.5-1-0.7-1.6l-2.2,0.5c0.4,1.7,1.3,3.1,2.7,4c1.4,0.9,3.4,1.4,5.9,1.4c1.4,0,2.6-0.2,3.7-0.5c1-0.3,1.9-0.8,2.6-1.3
    c0.7-0.6,1.2-1.2,1.5-2c0.3-0.8,0.5-1.6,0.5-2.5C171.2,154.8,171.1,154.2,170.9,153.6z"/>
  </g>
  <g>
   <path class="st0"  d="M56.8,181.6v-5.3c0-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.5c0-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5c0-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.4c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5
    c0,0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4l-2.3,5.4h-0.7l-2.4-5.4c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4
    c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5c0,0.2,0,0.3,0,0.5c0,0.1,0,0.3,0,0.5c0,0.2,0,0.3,0,0.5v5.3h-0.7v-7.6h1l2.5,5.7c0,0,0,0.1,0.1,0.2
    c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.2-0.5c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4c0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.2l2.4-5.7h1
    v7.6H56.8z"/>
   <path class="st0"  d="M76.3,181.6v-7.6h5v0.6h-4.3v2.7H81v0.6h-3.9v3h4.5v0.6H76.3z"/>
   <path class="st0"   d="M106.4,177.7c0,0.6-0.1,1.2-0.3,1.7c-0.2,0.5-0.5,0.9-0.8,1.2c-0.3,0.3-0.7,0.6-1.2,0.7
    c-0.4,0.2-0.9,0.2-1.5,0.2h-2.8v-7.6h2.4c0.6,0,1.1,0.1,1.6,0.2c0.5,0.1,0.9,0.4,1.3,0.7c0.4,0.3,0.6,0.7,0.8,1.2
    C106.3,176.5,106.4,177,106.4,177.7z M105.6,177.7c0-0.5-0.1-1-0.2-1.4c-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.7-0.7-1c-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.4-1-0.5
    c-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.2-1.3-0.2h-1.6v6.3h1.9c0.4,0,0.8-0.1,1.2-0.2c0.4-0.1,0.7-0.3,1-0.6c0.3-0.3,0.5-0.6,0.6-1
    C105.5,178.7,105.6,178.2,105.6,177.7z"/>
   <path class="st0" d="M124.9,181.6v-7.6h0.8v7.6H124.9z"/>
   <path class="st0"  d="M149.5,181.6l-0.9-2.4h-3.4l-0.9,2.4h-0.8l3-7.6h0.9l3,7.6H149.5z M147.4,175.9c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5
    c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3c0-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.1c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.2c0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3
    c0,0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5l-1,2.7h3L147.4,175.9z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
    
</g>
<g class="icon">
 <g>
  <g>
   <path class="st1" d="M102.3,18.5c-4.8-0.1-9.5,0.5-14,1.8c-4.5,1.3-8.8,3.3-12.7,6c-3.9,2.7-7.4,6.1-10.2,10.1
    c-2.9,4.1-5,8.9-6.2,14.2c-0.4,2.2-0.5,4.5-0.1,6.7c0.3,2.2,1.1,4.4,2.1,6.5c1,2.1,2.4,4,4,5.6c1.6,1.7,3.5,3.1,5.5,4.1
    c0.8,0.4,1.6,0.7,2.4,1c0.8,0.3,1.7,0.5,2.5,0.6c0.9,0.1,1.7,0.2,2.6,0.2c0.9,0,1.8,0,2.7-0.2c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.2
    c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.2c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.2c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.2c-2.8-1.4-5.1-3.2-7-5.4c-1.9-2.2-3.3-4.6-4.3-7.3
    c-1-2.6-1.5-5.4-1.7-8.3c-0.1-2.8,0.1-5.7,0.7-8.6c0.2-0.7,0.4-1.4,0.7-2.2c0.3-0.8,0.6-1.6,1.1-2.5c0.4-0.9,0.9-1.8,1.4-2.7
    c0.5-0.9,1.1-1.8,1.8-2.8c1.7-2.5,3.7-4.7,6-6.6c2.3-1.9,4.9-3.5,7.6-4.8c2.7-1.3,5.5-2.4,8.4-3.2
    C96.6,19.3,99.5,18.7,102.3,18.5"/>
  </g>
  <g>
   <path class="st2" d="M124.8,23.5c-4.3-2.1-9.1-3.5-13.8-4.2c-4.8-0.7-9.7-0.7-14.4,0c-4.7,0.8-9.2,2.3-13.1,4.7
    c-4,2.4-7.4,5.8-9.8,10.1c-1.4,1.9-2.4,4-2.9,6.3c-0.6,2.3-0.7,4.8-0.3,7.1c0.4,2.4,1.3,4.7,2.7,6.7c1.4,2,3.3,3.8,5.8,5
    c-1.3-2.7-2.1-5.7-2.5-8.7c-0.3-3-0.2-6,0.5-8.9c0.6-2.8,1.7-5.5,3.3-7.9c1.5-2.3,3.5-4.3,5.9-5.8c0.5-0.4,1.2-0.8,1.8-1.3
    c0.7-0.4,1.4-0.9,2.3-1.3c0.8-0.4,1.7-0.9,2.7-1.3c0.9-0.4,2-0.8,3-1.2c2.6-0.8,5.3-1.4,7.9-1.7c2.7-0.3,5.4-0.3,8.1-0.1
    c2.7,0.2,5.4,0.7,8.1,1.5c2.7,0.8,5.4,1.8,8,3c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.9,0.4c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.9,0.5c0.3,0.2,0.6,0.3,0.9,0.5
    s0.6,0.3,0.9,0.5c-0.5-0.4-1.1-0.8-1.6-1.1c-0.6-0.4-1.1-0.7-1.7-1.1c-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.7-1.7-1C126,24.1,125.4,23.8,124.8,23.5"/>
  </g>
  <g>
   <path class="st3" d="M122.2,23.5c-0.8-0.4-1.7-0.8-2.6-1.1c-0.9-0.4-1.8-0.7-2.7-1c-0.9-0.3-1.8-0.6-2.7-0.8
    c-0.9-0.2-1.9-0.5-2.8-0.6c-3.5-0.5-7.3-0.3-10.9,0.5c-3.7,0.9-7.2,2.4-10.1,4.5c-3,2.2-5.4,4.9-6.8,8.2
    c-1.4,3.3-1.7,7.2-0.4,11.4c0.7-3,1.9-5.7,3.6-8.2c1.6-2.4,3.7-4.5,6-6.3c2.3-1.7,4.8-3.1,7.5-4c2.7-0.9,5.4-1.5,8.3-1.5
    c0.7,0,1.4,0,2.3,0c0.8,0,1.7,0.1,2.6,0.2c0.9,0.1,1.9,0.3,2.9,0.5c1,0.2,2.1,0.5,3.2,0.8c0.6,0.1,1.1,0.3,1.7,0.4
    c0.6,0.2,1.1,0.3,1.6,0.5c0.5,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.6,0.6c0.5,0.2,1,0.4,1.5,0.7c2.2,1.1,4.2,2.4,6.1,3.9c1.9,1.5,3.7,3.2,5.5,5.1
    c1.8,1.9,3.5,3.8,5.1,5.9c1.7,2,3.4,4.1,5.1,6.2c-1.5-2.8-3.1-5.5-5-8.1c-1.8-2.5-3.8-4.9-6-7.1c-2.2-2.2-4.5-4.2-6.9-6
    C127.5,26.4,124.9,24.8,122.2,23.5"/>
  </g>
  <g>
   <path class="st4" d="M123.8,28.9c-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.8-0.4c-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.8-0.4c-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.8-0.3
    c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.8-0.3c-2.5-0.6-5-0.9-7.5-0.7c-2.5,0.2-5,0.7-7.3,1.6c-2.3,0.9-4.5,2.3-6.3,4c-1.9,1.7-3.5,3.9-4.6,6.4
    c2.2-1.7,4.5-3.1,7-4.2c2.4-1,4.9-1.7,7.4-2c2.5-0.3,5-0.3,7.6,0.2c2.5,0.4,5.1,1.2,7.6,2.4c0.3,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.4
    c0.3,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.4c0.3,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.4c0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.5c0.6,0.4,1.2,0.8,1.9,1.3c0.7,0.5,1.3,1.1,2,1.7
    c0.7,0.6,1.4,1.3,2.2,2.1c0.7,0.8,1.5,1.6,2.2,2.5c2.1,2.4,3.7,5,4.9,7.9c1.3,2.9,2.2,6,2.9,9.2c0.7,3.2,1.1,6.6,1.3,10
    c0.2,3.4,0.3,6.9,0.2,10.2c1-5.3,1.3-10.8,0.9-16.1c-0.3-5.2-1.4-10.4-3.1-15.1c-1.7-4.7-4.1-9-7.3-12.7
    C132.5,34.3,128.6,31.2,123.8,28.9"/>
  </g>
  <g>
   <path class="st5" d="M130,43.3c-1.5-0.7-3.1-1.3-4.6-1.6c-1.6-0.4-3.2-0.5-4.8-0.5c-1.6,0.1-3.2,0.4-4.7,0.9
    c-1.5,0.6-3.1,1.4-4.5,2.6c1.2-0.3,2.5-0.6,3.7-0.7c1.2-0.1,2.4-0.1,3.5,0c1.1,0.1,2.3,0.3,3.4,0.7c1.1,0.3,2.2,0.7,3.2,1.2
    c1.4,0.7,2.8,1.5,4.1,2.5c1.3,1,2.5,2.1,3.7,3.3c1.1,1.2,2.2,2.6,3.2,4c1,1.4,1.8,2.9,2.6,4.5c0.3,0.6,0.5,1.3,0.8,2.1
    c0.2,0.8,0.5,1.6,0.7,2.5c0.2,0.9,0.4,1.9,0.6,2.9c0.2,1,0.3,2.1,0.4,3.3c0.4,3.1,0.3,6.3-0.3,9.5c-0.6,3.2-1.6,6.3-3,9.4
    c-1.4,3.1-3.1,6.1-5.1,8.9c-2,2.8-4.3,5.5-6.7,7.8c3.8-3.1,7.1-6.7,9.8-10.6c2.7-3.8,4.8-8,6.3-12.3c1.5-4.2,2.3-8.6,2.5-13
    c0.2-4.3-0.2-8.7-1.4-12.9c-0.5-1.5-1.2-3-2.1-4.4c-0.9-1.4-1.9-2.8-3.1-4c-1.2-1.2-2.4-2.4-3.8-3.4
    C132.9,44.9,131.5,44,130,43.3"/>
  </g>
  <g>
   <path class="st6" d="M130.8,53.6c-0.7-0.4-1.5-0.7-2.3-0.9c-0.8-0.3-1.6-0.5-2.4-0.7c-0.8-0.2-1.7-0.3-2.5-0.4
    c-0.9-0.1-1.7-0.1-2.6-0.1c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.2c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.2c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2
    c2.7,1.3,5,3,6.9,4.9c1.9,2,3.3,4.2,4.4,6.6c1,2.4,1.6,5,1.8,7.6c0.2,2.7-0.1,5.4-0.9,8c-0.2,0.7-0.4,1.4-0.6,2.2
    c-0.3,0.8-0.6,1.6-1,2.5c-0.4,0.9-0.8,1.8-1.3,2.7c-0.5,0.9-1.1,1.9-1.7,2.9c-2.1,2.5-4.4,5-6.9,7.2c-2.6,2.3-5.4,4.3-8.4,6.1
    c-3,1.8-6.3,3.2-9.8,4.1c-3.5,1-7.1,1.5-10.9,1.4c3.4,0.3,6.6,0.1,9.6-0.3c3-0.4,5.9-1.1,8.7-2.1c2.8-1,5.4-2.2,8-3.6
    c2.6-1.4,5.1-3,7.5-4.7c2.7-2.2,5.1-4.8,7.1-7.4c2-2.7,3.5-5.5,4.6-8.4c1.1-2.9,1.7-5.9,1.8-8.9c0.1-3-0.3-6-1.4-9
    c-0.4-1.2-0.9-2.3-1.5-3.3c-0.6-1-1.3-2-2.1-2.9c-0.8-0.9-1.7-1.7-2.7-2.4C132.9,54.8,131.9,54.2,130.8,53.6"/>
  </g>
  <g>
   <path class="st7" d="M120.9,65.1c2,2.3,3.2,4.9,3.9,7.5c0.7,2.7,0.7,5.5,0.2,8.2c-0.5,2.8-1.5,5.6-2.9,8.2
    c-1.5,2.6-3.4,5.1-5.6,7.2c-0.5,0.5-1.2,1-1.9,1.5c-0.7,0.5-1.5,1-2.4,1.6c-0.9,0.5-1.8,1-2.8,1.5c-1,0.5-2.1,1-3.3,1.5
    c-3,1-6,1.7-9.2,2.1c-3.1,0.4-6.3,0.5-9.5,0.2c-3.2-0.2-6.3-0.8-9.3-1.6c-3-0.8-5.9-1.9-8.7-3.3c-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.3-0.9-0.5
    c-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.3-0.9-0.5c-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.3-0.9-0.5c-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.3-0.9-0.5c0.6,0.5,1.2,1,1.8,1.5c0.6,0.5,1.3,0.9,1.9,1.4
    c0.6,0.4,1.3,0.9,2,1.2c0.7,0.4,1.4,0.8,2.1,1.1c2.3,1.1,4.7,2,7.1,2.7c2.5,0.7,5,1.1,7.5,1.4c2.6,0.3,5.1,0.4,7.7,0.3
    c2.5-0.1,5.1-0.3,7.6-0.6c4-0.7,7.8-1.9,11.2-3.4c3.3-1.6,6.3-3.5,8.7-5.9c2.4-2.4,4.3-5.1,5.5-8.3c1.2-3.1,1.8-6.6,1.6-10.4
    c0-1.4-0.2-2.8-0.7-4.1c-0.4-1.3-1.1-2.6-1.9-3.8c-0.8-1.2-1.9-2.2-3.1-3.2C123.7,66.7,122.4,65.9,120.9,65.1"/>
  </g>
  <g>
   <path class="st8" d="M116.9,76.9c0.1,3.2-0.3,6.2-1.4,8.9c-1,2.7-2.6,5.1-4.6,7.1c-2,2.1-4.4,3.8-7.1,5.1
    c-2.7,1.3-5.7,2.2-8.9,2.7c-0.7,0.1-1.6,0.1-2.5,0.2c-0.9,0-1.9,0-2.9,0c-1-0.1-2.1-0.2-3.3-0.3c-1.2-0.1-2.4-0.4-3.6-0.6
    c-0.7-0.1-1.3-0.3-2-0.5c-0.6-0.2-1.3-0.4-1.9-0.6c-0.6-0.2-1.3-0.5-1.9-0.7c-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.5-1.8-0.8c-2.4-1.2-4.6-2.6-6.7-4.2
    c-2.1-1.6-4.1-3.4-6.1-5.4c-1.9-1.9-3.7-3.9-5.4-6c-1.7-2-3.3-4.1-4.8-6.1c1.1,2.7,2.4,5.3,4,7.9c1.6,2.6,3.4,5,5.5,7.3
    c2.1,2.3,4.4,4.5,6.9,6.4c2.5,1.9,5.2,3.6,8,5c2.6,1.3,5.2,2.3,8,3c2.7,0.7,5.5,1.1,8.4,1.2c2.8,0.1,5.7-0.2,8.5-0.8
    c2.8-0.6,5.7-1.7,8.4-3.1c2.1-1.2,3.9-2.9,5.4-4.8c1.4-1.9,2.5-4.1,3.2-6.5c0.6-2.3,0.9-4.8,0.7-7.2
    C118.7,81.6,118.1,79.2,116.9,76.9"/>
  </g>
  <g>
   <path class="st9" d="M56.4,48.5c-1.1,4.4-1.4,8.9-1.1,13.5c0.3,4.7,1.4,9.4,3.1,13.8c1.8,4.5,4.3,8.8,7.6,12.5
    c3.3,3.8,7.4,6.9,12.1,9.3c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.9,0.4c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.9,0.4c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,1,0.4c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,1,0.4
    c3.2,0.9,6.5,1.2,9.5,0.8c3-0.4,5.9-1.3,8.4-2.8c2.5-1.5,4.6-3.4,6.3-5.8c1.7-2.3,2.9-5.1,3.5-8.1c-1.3,2.5-3.1,4.5-5.3,6.2
    c-2.2,1.7-4.8,3-7.6,3.8c-2.8,0.8-5.7,1.2-8.7,1c-2.9-0.2-5.8-0.9-8.5-2.2c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.4
    c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.4c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.4c-0.7-0.3-1.4-0.7-2.2-1.2c-0.8-0.5-1.6-1-2.4-1.6c-0.8-0.6-1.7-1.3-2.6-2
    c-0.9-0.7-1.8-1.5-2.6-2.4c-2.4-2.6-4.3-5.4-5.8-8.2c-1.5-2.8-2.6-5.7-3.5-8.7c-0.8-3-1.3-6-1.5-9C56.2,54.6,56.2,51.6,56.4,48.5
    "/>
  </g>
  <g>
   <path class="st10" d="M71.1,25c-3.8,3.4-7.1,7.6-9.6,12.2c-2.6,4.7-4.4,9.9-5.2,15.2c-0.8,5.4-0.5,11,1.3,16.4
    c1.8,5.5,5,10.7,9.9,15.2c0.3,0.3,0.7,0.5,1,0.8c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.5,1,0.7c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.4,1.1,0.6c0.4,0.2,0.7,0.4,1.1,0.6
    c2.1,1,4.3,1.7,6.5,2c2.2,0.3,4.4,0.2,6.6-0.2c2.1-0.4,4.2-1.2,6-2.4c1.8-1.2,3.5-2.7,4.9-4.6c-1.7,0.7-3.4,1.3-5.2,1.6
    c-1.8,0.3-3.6,0.5-5.4,0.4c-1.8-0.1-3.7-0.3-5.4-0.8c-1.8-0.4-3.5-1.1-5.1-1.9c-1.2-0.6-2.3-1.3-3.4-2.1c-1.1-0.8-2.1-1.6-3-2.6
    c-0.9-1-1.8-2-2.5-3.1c-0.7-1.1-1.4-2.3-1.9-3.6c-0.4-0.6-0.7-1.4-1.1-2.2c-0.4-0.8-0.7-1.7-1.1-2.6c-0.3-0.9-0.7-1.9-0.9-3
    c-0.3-1.1-0.5-2.2-0.8-3.3c-0.1-3.2,0.1-6.3,0.5-9.5c0.4-3.1,1.1-6.1,2-9c0.9-2.8,2.1-5.6,3.6-8.1C67.2,29.4,69,27.1,71.1,25"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform" 
   attributeType="XML" 
   type="rotate" 
   from="0 100 62" 
   to="360 100 62" 
   dur="4s" 
   repeatCount="0" 
         fill="freeze"           
    /> 
    
</g>
</svg>

</body>
```

Comment: The color and fill you are setting in the style of your img tag will do nothing. margin-top will work as it will apply to the img tag rather than its contents.

Comment: I am using this css fill in svg file which content i want to fadein... @Robert Logsin

Comment: I have edited my post, so it should be better explained now.

Comment: Can you send me your post link

Comment: @BasySilver you can't use a css file if the SVG is being used as an image. It **must** be in the file itself.

Comment: If you want some more explanation you can check this out: http://thoughtfulweb.com/thoughts/on/the-best-way-to-add-an-svg-image-to-your-website

Comment: @BasySilver Thank you so much for your efforts. I tried all this but not getting any good output. Can you please make a demo in jsfiddle for this code i can send you svg file

Comment: @user2841671 you can edit your question and post your SVG code into it. Then i can help you better.

Comment: @BasySilver Yes i have added it here https://jsfiddle.net/Shiv33/ufaLtu5d/ please check

Comment: I took the code of the svg and pasted it into your HTML code. Now u got the same animation, but can manipulate it much better. https://jsfiddle.net/ufaLtu5d/1/

Comment: @user2841671 the animation is actually working pretty fine. You just need to add `.text {fill:white;}` again so you can see it ;-) 
See https://jsfiddle.net/ufaLtu5d/3/

Comment: Edited and added a snippet in my post above

Comment: @BasySilver yes i tried this before but when i am trying to include in image it stop doing this. This is exactly the problem